# Contact Form: Why won't this form validate?

Tags: php, jquery, validation, forms, contact-form

I have a contact form at the bottom of a, (single page business/portfolio), website.

The script above my DOCTYPE looks like this.

```
<?php
//If the form is submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    //Check to make sure that the name field is not empty
    if(trim($_POST['contactname']) == '') {
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $name = trim($_POST['contactname']);
    }

    //Check to make sure that the subject field is not empty
    if(trim($_POST['subject']) == '') {
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $subject = trim($_POST['subject']);
    }

    //Check to make sure sure that a valid email address is submitted
    if(trim($_POST['email']) == '')  {
        $hasError = true;
    } else if (!eregi("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$",   trim($_POST['email']))) {
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    }

    //Check to make sure comments were entered
    if(trim($_POST['comment']) == '') {
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
            $comments = stripslashes(trim($_POST['message']));
        } else {
            $comments = trim($_POST['message']);
        }
    }

    //If there is no error, send the email
    if(!isset($hasError)) {
        $emailTo = 'myemail@gmail.com'; //Put your own email address here
        $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nSubject: $subject \n\nComments:\n $comments";
        $headers = 'From: My Site <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

        mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
        $emailSent = true;
    }
}
?>
```

The JQuery validation does work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").validate();
});
</script>
```

The contact form:

```
<div class="grid_8">
    <?php if(isset($hasError)) { //If errors are found ?>
        <p class="error">Please check if you've filled all the fields with valid information. Thank you.</p>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if(isset($emailSent) && $emailSent == true) { //If email is sent ?>
        <p><strong>Email Successfully Sent!</strong></p>
        <p>Thank you <strong><?php echo $name;?></strong> for using my contact form! Your email was successfully sent and I will be in touch with you soon.</p>
    <?php } ?>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"> 
        <div> 
            <label for="name">Your Name:</label> 
            <div> 
                <input type="text" name="contactname" class="required" /> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
        <div> 
            <label for="email">Your Email:</label> 
            <div> 
                <input type="text" name="email" class="required email" /> 
            </div>   
        </div> 
        <div> 
            <label for="subject">Subject:</label> 
            <div> 
                <input type="text" name="subject" class="required" /> 
            </div>
        </div> 
        <div> 
            <label for="comments">Comments:</label> 
            <div> 
                <textarea name="comment" name="comment" class="required"></textarea> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
        <div> 
            <input id="button" type="submit" value="SEND" /> 
        </div> 
    </form>
    </div>
```

When you submit the form, the email does not get sent, nor any verification from php. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do note that eregi() is deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One quick obvious issue, although I have many less critical ones. Simply put you'r checking for `$_POST['submit']` put there is `name="submit"` in your form.

So change:

```
 <input id="button" type="submit" value="SEND" />
```

To:

```
 <input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="SEND" />
```

Or change:

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

To:

```
 if(count($_POST))
 // OR
 if(!empty($_POST))
```

Either one will fix your problem

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why `isset($_POST['submit'])` should return true when you have no field with `name="submit"` in your form.

What I prefer to do is using an array for all the required data:

```
<!-- ... -->
<input type="text" name="mail[contactname]" class="required" /> 
<!-- ... -->
<input type="text" name="mail[email]" class="required email" /> 
<!-- ... -->
<input type="text" name="mail[subject]" class="required" /> 
<!-- ... -->
<textarea name="comment" name="mail[comment]" class="required"></textarea> 
<!-- ... -->
```

And then asking for that array

```
if (isset($_POST['mail']))
  // ...
```